# How does preg_replace() understand '${1}1,$3' in $replacement argument?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am having a hard time to understand the preg_replace().
This is what I have got so far.
`preg_replace($patter, $replacement, $string)`
But, It confuses me when there is capturing groups in replacement.
But still I get some of it. Like below

`preg_replace('/(\w+)/', 'hello', 'say hello!')` 
I know it will result in 'hello hello!'.
I can do something more with capturing group.
`preg_replace('/(\w+)/','\1 Hello', 'Say World!',1)`

It will result in 'Say Hello World'.

This is what I don't get.

```
<?php
$string = 'April 15, 2003';
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
$replacement = '${1}1,$3';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
Output:
April1,2003
```

What `${1}1,$3` means?

What's the difference between using `$1` `\1` and `<\1>`
What does  this `${1}1` mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question!

#### For substitution parts

My guess is that <`\1`> and `$1` `${1}` are pretty much the same, addressing capturing groups, except one of which has an extra `<>`.

I think we are using `${1}1` since if we don't, we would have had `$11`, which does not simply exist, since we don't have that 11 capturing groups, we only have 3 of those, similar story for `\11`.

`${1}1,$3` means the first capturing group, `${1}`, and the number `1`, and third capturing group, `$3`.

#### Inside the Regular Expression

> When we use `\1` or `\2` **inside a regular expression**, not as a
>   substitute, it would reference back the prior capturing groups `$1` and `$2`, which is the same as `\1` and `2` **in the substitute** section, which I also think that might create reasonable and valid confusions.

#### [Please see this demo for back-referencing.](https://regex101.com/r/Jm68cX/1/)

#### Reference

[Named Capturing Groups and Backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)

Comment: So,  `$1` and `\1` are same. We are capturing first matched group? I was confused `(?<name>)` which is a named group. Can you give me any link to clear my doubts on capturing groups and named capturing group? Your answer is very helpful.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and your support, thanks a lot.